# Theme support in Angular Project

Tags: angular, less, themes

I have a base project(lets call it template project) written in angular2 that provides some basic components. This base project is used in many other projects(lets call it solution projects). In both template and solution projects i am using LESS for styling.

The workflow is that i add some component in my template project, publish it to npm local repository and then i consume it in solution projects.

I want to add theme support in my solution but i don't know how to achieve that.

First thing i thought is to keep different less veriables for different themes(just an idea). But the problem that i face is that when i consume my template project in solution it contains the bundled version of the component that means the less is already compiled due to which i can not use less veriables to override the styles.

I read about `host-context` from [here](http://anasfirdousi.com/creating-themeable-components-in-angular.html)  but still not sure how it will fit in my scenario.

Has anyone done any similer kind of work ? Please help.